# how to use c++ IDLs and Type libraries in Java

Tags: java, c++, idl

I am trying to use DLL in java using JNA.

but for creating JNA interface we need to know functions in dll.

I came to know that IDLs can be used to create these interfaces automatically.

I want to ask how C++ IDLs and type libraries can be used with Java.